# how to convert this formula into matrix form?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Consider the following form
$$\sum_{1\leq i,j,n}a_{ij}\cos(\theta_i-\theta_j)$$
where $A=\{a_{ij}\}$ is a $n\times n$ matrice.

This form can be written as
$$\frac{1}{2}\big<A,I_n-QQ^T\big>$$
where $Q:=[x\ y]\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 2}$, $x:=[\cos(\theta_1),\cdots,\cos(\theta_n)]^T$, $y:=[\sin(\theta_1),\cdots,\sin(\theta_n)]^T$, and $I_n$ is the identity matrix. Moreover, $\big<U,V\big>$ denotes $\text{trace}(U^TV)$.

**My question is:**

How to transform $$\sum_{1\leq i,j,n}a_{ij}g(\theta_i-\theta_j)$$ into matrix from when $g$ is an arbitrary function? I realized that the above approach does not work anymore when $g\neq\cos$.

Comment: well, you can expand $g$ in a Fourier series, if toy dont mind an infinite series of of $\sin(n\theta_i), \cos(n\theta_i)$

Comment: @user619894 In fact, I don't mind that it is expanded as finite Fourier series. Could you give me an explicit example? I also tried Fourier series but it does not work as well (maybe I did wrong calculation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $g(u)$ is periodic, then $g(u)=\sum_n A_n \cos(nu) + B_n \sin(nu)$, and $$\sum_{ij} a_{ij} g(\theta_{ij})=\sum_{ij}\sum_{n} a_{ij} \big[A_{n} \cos(n\theta_{ij}) + B_{n} \sin(n\theta_{ij})\big]$$
That is
$$\sum_n A_{n} \big [\sum_{ij} a_{ij} \cos(n\theta_{ij})\big ] + \sum_n B_n \big [\sum_{ij} a_{ij} \sin(n\theta_{ij})\big ]$$
Each term in the square bracket can be written in terms of your original decomposition.

If $g$ is not periodic, The exercise must be repeated with a Fourier integral.